# Create index on multicolumn type

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres 9.6

I am trying to create an index on a type adt_flds with a field also named `adt_flds`

```
 create type adt_flds as
(
      created_at timestamp
    , updated_at timestamp
    , created_by text
    , updated_by text
    , created_by_client_addr inet
    , updated_by_client_addr inet
    , created_by_client_cmptr text
    , updated_by_client_cmptr text
);
```

My attempt is as follows for

schema = document

table = training_complete_history

field = adt_flds

field column = created_at

SQL

```
create index training_complete_history_adt_flds_index
on document.training_complete_history ((adt_flds).created_at);
```

Unfortunately, my attempt yields the following error.

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 114.

How would I properly index `created_at` inside `adt_flds`?

Comment: What's the *question*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I went ahead and changed the question for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra pair of parentheses around the indexed term if it is not a column or a function call.

In the words of [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

> The expression usually must be written with surrounding parentheses, as shown in the syntax. However, the parentheses can be omitted if the expression has the form of a function call.

```
CREATE INDEX training_complete_history_adt_flds_index
ON document.training_complete_history (((adt_flds).created_at));
```

I think it is a bad idea to use a composite type if you want to use parts of it in a `WHERE` or join condition. It violates the first normal form.

Comment: I don't disagree. However the creation of this was not in my control. There was a complaint of too many audit fields at our organization. This was the solution derived at the time to resolve the complaints.